Python function works with Process but not with apply_async
from scripts import classify_reads
from multiprocessing import Value, Process, Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

I have some code that functions well using multiprocessing (python package multiprocess), but I was using Process. I want now to make asynchronous to allow the user to set a number of threads.
A simplification of the code:
shared_k_size = Value('i', k_size)
shared_n_consec_matches = Value('i', n_consec_matches)
shared_output = Value(c_wchar_p, args["output"])
shared_anchor_proportion_cutoff = Value('f', anchor_proportion_cutoff)
# creates a custom manager for a set in shared memory
class CustomManager(BaseManager):
     # nothing
     pass
CustomManager.register('shared_set', set)
manager = CustomManager()
manager.start()
shared_kmer_set = manager.shared_set()

def classify_reads(fastq_file, bloom_filter, kmer_size, n_consecutive_matches, output, shared_anchor_kmer_set):
    kmer_set = set()
    # populates the kmer_set
    print(len(kmer_set))
    shared_anchor_kmer_set.update(anchor_kmer_set)

#this works:
processes = [Process(target=classify_reads, args=(i, present_kmers_bf, shared_k_size.value, shared_n_consec_matches.value, shared_output.value, shared_kmer_set)) for i in args["input"]]
    for i in range(0, len(processes), args["threads"]):
        for process in processes[i:i + args["threads"]]:
            process.start()
    for process in processes:
         process.join()
    for process in processes:
        process.terminate()

#this doesnt
    with Pool(processes=args["threads"]) as pool:
        print(f"starting async")
        for i in args["input"]:
            try :
                pool.apply_async(classify_reads.classify_reads, args=(i, present_kmers_bf,
                                                                  shared_k_size.value,
                                                                  shared_n_consec_matches.value,
                                                                  shared_output.value,
                                                                  shared_kmer_set,))
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

I successfully changed the rest of the code, which uses almost the same arguments (manager included), to apply_async. The present_kmers_bf is a bloom filter from pybloomfilter (https://pypi.org/project/pybloomfiltermmap3/).
My hypothesis is that mmap files may not be directly compatible with apply_async, but the documentation says it is pickle-able.

So I went digging again, and found that the bloom filter was only partially pickled see (https://github.com/prashnts/pybloomfiltermmap3/issues/43):
The bloomfilters don't have reduce and setstate functions and so cannot be pickled. In particular, this prevents in-memory bloomfilters being used in multiprocessing.Pool or in cloud lambda functions, etc.

This was solved very recently in pybloomfiltermmap3 v0.6.0 after I had the issue first, but the changed induces a bug (process being killed) due to an issue with cython (https://github.com/prashnts/pybloomfiltermmap3/issues/55) recently introduced. I'll have to wait for this to be solved before trying again.
